# Interpretation of mars rover images

Tags: mars, perseverance, chemistry, geology, scientific-data

I’ve been obsessed with the perseverance images, specially the images from the SHERLOC-WATSON system- the UV camera tricked out with racing stripes and fuzzy dice hanging from its rear-view mirror (metaphorically speaking). You can adjust the images manually to see what is fluorescing and you can tell by the file name which wavelength filter they are using so you can kinda figure out what chemical group is being highlighted but I’m a chemist, not a marine biologist so I’m having a hard time figuring out what they suspect those samples are.

There are some im pretty sure they suspect are ocular but those are the only ones I’m reasonably sure of. Since NASA is being tight lipped about the interpretations but open with the raw data does anyone have any tips? I see NASA posted some code which looks like does some of the image processing for you but not sure about interpretation.

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding exactly what your question is and what exactly you expect an answer to provide. The only question mark in your question is "...does anyone have any tips?" Do you want tips on how scientists decide "...what they suspect those samples are..."? Are you asking "How do scientists interpret fluorescence seen in SHERLOC-WATSON UV camera and how do they identify specific compounds from this data?" It would be great if you added some links - ideally to some specific measurements where scientists actually do suspect they know what they are looking at. *Thanks!*

Comment: ...and *Welcome to Stack Exchange!*

Comment: Why would you think you'd want to be a marine biologist to interpret those images? None of what we see on those images is related to biological fluorescence (you would have heard about it otherwise..), but it's all just good old minerals.

Comment: NASA has made it crystal clear they are being über conservative and will NOT use the L word until they have physical samples in hand. They want to be super sure. That said, I see they have done studies on suspected ocular structures and looking  at fluorescence you can see that one of the “rocks” physically sampled has structures of different chemical compositions which look and are located similar to organs of a flash frozen squid-Not that it carries much weight but I’m confident in my interpretation and just feel 10 years is better spent discussing what happened, not waiting.

Comment: When they bust out Watson Sherloc,  the sample is suspected to be biological. I am able to see the object they are targeting but I have no clue what that object might be other than a few suspected eye samples. Im asking if anyone has hint at interpreting the rest of them. Maybe based on the wavelength filter and chemicals groups targeted?

Comment: @AtmosphericPrisonEscape [In its first 400 days on Mars, NASA’s Perseverance rover may have found a diverse collection of organics – carbon-based molecules considered the building blocks of life – thanks to SHERLOC, an innovative instrument on the rover’s robotic arm.](https://www.jpl.nasa.gov/news/nasas-perseverance-rover-sees-mars-in-a-new-light#:~:text=a%20diverse%20collection%20of%20organics%20%E2%80%93%20carbon%2Dbased%20molecules%20considered%20the%20building%20blocks%20of%20life)

Comment: @AtmosphericPrisonEscape see also Nature [Diverse organic-mineral associations in Jezero crater, Mars](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41586-023-06143-z) While these organic molecules (associated with minerals but not minerals themselves) won't be the same ones that were in the water thought to have flowed there, they are thought to possibly have originated from other marine organic material. So yeah not a marine biologist, but maybe an organic chemist or "marine archeological chemist".

Comment: @TomSmith "When they bust out Watson Sherloc, the sample is suspected to be biological." Not necessarily biological now, but potentially (or not) of biological origin, the way crude oil on Earth has a biological origin but is not considered actually biological now.

Comment: [SHERLOC enables non-contact, spatially resolved, and highly sensitivity detection and characterization of **organics and minerals**...  The instrument goals are to assess past aqueous history, detect the presence and preservation of potential biosignatures, and to support selection of return samples. To do this, SHERLOC measures CHNOPS-containing mineralogy, measures the distribution and type of organics preserved at the surface, and correlates them to textural features.](https://mars.nasa.gov/mars2020/spacecraft/instruments/sherloc/for-scientists/) "organic" and "biological" not same thing.